# EF converting of query with sql index

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, indexing

I have a table with 3 non-clustered indexes, but when I try to execute query using EF, like

```
entitiesQueryable = entitiesQueryable
                .Where(e => e.Value.ToLower().Contains(model.Value.ToLower()));
```

Ef convert query to

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[EntityType] AS [EntityType], 
[Extent1].[EntitySubType] AS [EntitySubType], 
[Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[FOMEntity2] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (CAST(CHARINDEX(LOWER('Varyence'), LOWER([Extent1].[Value])) AS int)) > 0
```

And it doesn`t wont to use my indexes!

[image: Query without indexes]

But If I`ll change filter type:

```
 WHERE [Value] = 'Varyence'
```

Indexes would be recognised. Check

[image: Query with index]

How can I avoid this? Thanks for help.

Comment: how do you imagine index structure for contains operator?

Comment: Sorry, dont understand your question.

Comment: short answer: it's impossible to use index for contains operator

Comment: also you can correct mysql tag to sql server since you are using SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing you can do here to improve performance is to enable full-text search and create [fulltext index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to [Konstantin Ershov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393752/konstantin-ershov), I found the best solution for me. EF really doesnt wont to use indexes with `CHARINDEX` operator, but indexes works fine with `LIKE`, so I changed my filter to

```
entitiesQueryable = entitiesQueryable
                .Where(e => e.Value.Contains(model.Value));
```

which EF convert to

```
  WHERE [Extent1].[Value] LIKE 'Varyence' ESCAPE N'~'
```

Comment: actually I don't see any changes in your C# code comparing to original. and the only reason why sql now uses index is because your like expression equals to just "=" operator in this form

Comment: I removed `.toLower()` construction

Comment: now I see. But it's really strange that EF translates .Contains to LIKE without '%'...

Comment: Yeah, but it works. Maybe it`s problems in sql profiler :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue is that you were doing a ToLower(), that prevented the index from being used.

By default SQL Server is case-insensitive, so you never need to write ToLower() in any of your queries.